# breakage vs breaking in "X denotes the spontaneous breakage/breaking of rotational symmetry"

Tags: academic-writing

In the sentence " X denotes the spontaneous breakage/breaking of rotational symmetry.", which is the best word to use in its context?

Comment: Thanks Stuart F.

Comment: I have never heard the phrase "breakage of symmetry".  Although symmetry is broken is common.

Comment: [*Breakage of symmetry*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22breakage+of+symmetry%22) appears to be common in the sciences.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on wider context, you could use one of the following:

- X denotes the spontaneous breaking of rotational symmetry
- X denotes a spontaneous break in rotational symmetry

You can also use "discontinuity" to denote a region where global surface properties break suddenly (flipping basis directions, loss of smoothness etc.)

Comment: Break can mean a temporary interruption, while breakage implies a permanent change: a lunch break vs a breakage of china.

Comment: On SE you are required to provide some sort of authority or argument to support your assertions. Please do so. Why do you think “breakage” is incorrect? You may well be right, but how can we tell?